# Python: Placing a image Based on a matrix

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

Alright, this is a little over my head so bear with me a little.
Me and a group of Students are working on a Tetris Project in Python 3.5

I'm handling the Gui and I'm having some trouble. I want to assign the coordinates of an image I put into the canvas according to the numbers within a matrix.

Example:

```
redB = PhotoImage(file="redBlock.gif")
self.myMatrix = [[0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,1,0]]

def BLOCKplace(self):
    for xx in range(0, len(self.myMatrix)):
        if self.myMatrix[xx] == 1:
            x = # Place in matrix where it equals 1, position multiplied 
                # by 24, the blocks are 24x24
            y = # Same as above
            canvas.create_image(x, y, image=redB, state="normal", tag="rB")
            canvas.update()
```

It's probably an amateur mistake I'm making or that I'm not seeing, but some help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you would turn your code into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and spell out what the *problem* is.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if self.myMatrix[xx] = 1:` have double equals `==` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer, though I want to thank Lucas Godoy and Rob Davis for at least pointing me in some direction.

```
def BLOCKplace(self):
    for row_index in range(len(self.myMatrix)):
        for column_index in range(len(self.myMatrix[row_index])):
            if self.myMatrix[row_index][column_index] == 1:
                canvas.create_image(row_index, column_index, image=redB, state="normal", tag="rB")
                canvas.update()
```

Basically, the problem was the If statement. This is Python 3.X I'm dealing with and it doesn't treat the values of the counted value in For loops EQUAL to the variable used for counting the loop. Setting up an if statement to check each of it's own individual cells solved the problem.

Though I wouldn't have made it this far without some structure or input from everyone else who posted here, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
def BLOCKplace(self):
    for row_index in range(len(self.myMatrix)):
        for column_index in range(len(self.myMatrix[row_index])):
            if column_index == 1:
                canvas.create_image(row_index, column_index, image=redB, state="normal", tag="rB")
                canvas.update()
```

Keep in mind:

- `range` default starting value is `0`. So `range(0, len(foo))` and `range(len(foo)` are identical.
- I've used `row_index` and `column_index` so that it's more clear what they mean. But since they are long names people tend to use just `x` and `y` to referer to matrix indexes.
- `range` is used for each iteration. It's usually a good idea to keep stores somewhere the row length and column length or your matrix so you don't need to repeat the `range` (i.e. all row lengths are identical).

Comment: I'll give it a shot and respond,

Comment: I think I goofed somewhere in what you posted. This does do a thorough check though it give me this weird set of blocks across the top of the screen.

http://i49.photobucket.com/albums/f294/shadetheexile/TetrisScreen_zpscmdtjslx.png

Either I messed up somewhere in my setup or something else.

Comment: It seems that you're using Tkinter to do the draw. I can look it up more thoroughly a little bit later. In the meantime did you try switching the `row_index` for the `column_index` on `create_image`? (i.e. `canvas.create_image(column_index, row_index, ...)`.

Comment: Instructor requested we try to do it in TKinter.

Comment: And I did, the problem remains the same though now the line of blocks is vertical! XD

Answer (score 0):

So, Python doesn't have matrices.  Instead, you get lists of lists.  So you `myMatrix` isn't a matrix, it is a list of length 4 that contains list of length of 4.

```
for xx in range(0, len(self.myMatrix)):
```

try

```
for xx in range(0, len(self.myMatrix)):
    for yy in range(0, len(self.myMatrix[xx])):
```

Comment: I'm aware that there are no Matrices in Python. I'm a college student trying to get by his assignments and different languages have their own way of labeling things from arrays to lists and dictionaries, so on and so forth. Calling it a matrix instead of a list because it helps me recognize what I'm dealing with and helps my other classmates who are dealing with the same thing.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  I was making that statement, because the way you were indexing into the myMatrix list would never have a scenario where self.myMatrix[xx] == 1.  the result of self.myMatrix[xx] would always be of type list.  I (falsely) assumed that your xx was an either an attempt at a row/column index or a belief that your matrix was a single list of length 16.